# Row Op for Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Question:**
>
> $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent $4 \times 4$ matrices. Determine the following:
>
> a). $B$ is obtained from $A$ by interchanging the 2nd and 3rd rows of $A$ and then multiplying the 4th row of $A$ by 6. Produce the elementary matrices in the given description which yields $B=E_2E_1A$.
>
> b). If $\det(3A^{−3}) = −24$, find $\det(BA)$. Show all steps.

I've tried finding an explanation for this question (part b) everywhere but I couldn't find it and this is the last resource I have.

So, I figured out the elementary matrices $E_1$ and $E_2$ which yield $B$ but how do I even start part b?

Answer (score 0):

Recall: $\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)$ if $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$.

So we have:
$$\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)=\det(E_2)\det(E_1)\det(A)\det(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the answer from jloo, refer to the properties of determinants:

Property 1:

If any 2 rows/columns are interchanged, then the sign of the determinant changes.

Property 2:

If a row/column is multiplied by a constant, k, then the determinant gets multiplied by k.